# UIView changes when iphone application starts from background

Tags: iphone, uiview, background

My iphone application has a user form under `UIViewController`.

When I out of application (go to background mode) and start application again some of my `UIView` changes its positions and sizes. (These `UIViews` depend on keyboard position) 
Definately somewhere is my fault.

I try to figure what is going on when application starts again from background and where the `UIView` changes can be done.

May be you can suggest any links to read.

Thank you.

Comment: A little code would help us a lot, it wont harm you to post some code ryt?

Answer (score 1):

The UIViewController's `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` methods get called every time the view is dumped from memory, something that commonly happens when the app goes into the background. Depending on your code, it's possible that you're storing some position data that's not getting cleared. If that's the case, you can either:

1. Change your code to better fit the Model-View-Controller pattern so that the positioning code and variables are all in the controller, and you appropriately clean things up in its 'viewWillDisappear`and`viewDidUnload` methods (the better way), or
2. Clear out whatever remnants are hanging around in your application delegate's applicationWillEnterBackground method.

Comment: That is the problem. My UIViewController doesn't call 'viewDidLoad', 'viewWillAppear' and so on. I do not get these calls when application go to background and restart again. I get 'applicationDidEnterBackground:' only, in my application delegate.